# Where can I access serverId?

Tags: filepond

I'd like to retrieve the serverId of an uploaded file. I tried to retrieve it in `onupdatefiles`, since it has a parameter which is `fileitems`. I assumed that I could use `fileItems[0].serverId` to fetch the uploaded file's servierId, but it showed `null`.
Who knows where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly the event `FilePond:updatefiles` is called **before** files are (successfully) uploaded. Thus the file object has a the serverId `null`.

I had a similar issue and I worked around that with the following code:

```js
document.addEventListener('FilePond:processfile', e => {
  global.newFileIds = global.filePond.getFiles().map(x => x.serverId)
})

document.addEventListener('FilePond:removefile', e => {
  global.newFileIds = global.filePond.getFiles().map(x => x.serverId)
})
```

FYI

- `FilePond:updatefiles` is called when new files are added to the upload queue . In my case this was called too early (and twice).
- `FilePond:processfile` is called after a file is successfully uploaded
- `FilePond:removefile` is called when a file is removed but does not have a `serverId` **ever** ([this is by design](https://github.com/pqina/filepond/issues/361#issuecomment-525383999) !?)